# What permissions does Sitecore need to manage Solr?

Tags: solr, configuration, security

- Solr 6.1.0 + Zookeeper + Basic Authentication
- Sitecore 8.0 Update-5

What are the minimum permissions required for Sitecore to manage Solr?

The official documentation says nothing about this AFAICT and the few blog posts I've found simply use "admin" as an example which is excessive.

If possible can you also express why the specified permission is sufficient?

Is there an official reference for this I haven't seen? Is it buried in old PDFs?

Comment: After you submit a request to Sitecore support for the purpose of getting their "official" response, can you share the outcome as an answer?

Comment: Indeed. I am asking there in parallel.

Comment: SC Support is always a joy: "The Solr permissions are specifically related to Solr, therefore we are not able to help you"